# Multiple instances of a WPF user control all use the same ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have an app that when I click a button loads a new `TabItem` with a `UserControl`. This works fine, but... When I click the Add button again, another `TabItem` is added with a new instance of the `UserControl`. Here comes the problem.
When I add some data in tab1 and switch to tab2, I also see the entered data there. How is this possible? I use a new `ViewModel` for each `UserControl` so how can both user controls on tab1 and tab2 show the same data.
It will probably be something stupid, but I can't find it...

Structure is like this: `MainWindow` loads a `UserControl` with only a `TabControl` on it.
After clicking an Add button in the menu a new `TabItem` is added with a new `UserControl` on it.

There are here on SO some issues that look like this but are different.

Here's some code.

`TabControl.xaml`:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" SelectedIndex="0">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:OverviewViewModel}">
                <my:OverviewControl />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel:MemberViewModel}">
                <my:MemberControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

`TabControl.cs`:

```
public TabControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new TabViewModel(true);
}
```

`TabViewModel` has a DP which holds the `TabItems`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TabItemsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "TabItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>), typeof(TabViewModel),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>()));
public ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel> TabItems
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<ITabViewModel>)GetValue(TabItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TabItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

The `UserControl` which gets loaded on the `TabItem`, `MemberControl.cs`:

```
public MemberControl()
{
  InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MemberViewModel{};
}
```

The `MemberControlViewModel`:

```
private MemberModel _memberModel = new MemberModel();

public MemberViewModel()
{
  Address = new AddressViewModel();
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("FirstName", typeof(string), typeof(MemberViewModel),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnFirstNameChanged));
public string FirstName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
}

public static void OnFirstNameChanged(DependencyObject m,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var d = m as MemberViewModel;
    if (d._memberModel != null)
        d._memberModel.FirstName = d.FirstName;
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LastNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LastName", typeof(string), typeof(MemberViewModel),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnLastNameChanged));
public string LastName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(LastNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LastNameProperty, value); }
}

public static void OnLastNameChanged(DependencyObject m,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var d = m as MemberViewModel;
    if (d._memberModel != null)
        d._memberModel.LastName = d.LastName;
}
```

And then at last the Command on my menu that actually adds the `MemberControl` as an new `TabItem` on the `TabControl`:

```
private void LoadNewMember(object notUsed)
{
    _tabViewModel.TabItems.Add(new MemberViewModel { Header = "New Member" });
    _addOverview.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Somewhere along the way I do something wrong with the binding, but as said, I can't find it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be setting the DataContext of each `MemberControl` twice.

Once when you add the `MemberViewModel` to your tab collection:

```
_tabViewModel.TabItems.Add(new MemberViewModel { Header = "New Member" });
```

this will create a `MemberControl` due to the DataTemplate you have set up.

Then, in your `MemberControl`'s constructor you then reset the DataContext to a new instance of `MemberViewModel`:

```
public MemberControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new MemberViewModel{};
}
```

I assume you are getting default values in both tabs due to this second `new`.

Comment: Indeed, I had an idea that that somehow isn't correct, but how to do it then? If I leave this line 'this.DataContext = new MemberViewModel{};' out of the MemberControl I think there is no binding from the MemberControl with the ViewModel, or am I wrong? Thx for confirming my suspicions.. :)

Comment: You can leave it out. Your DataTemplate already does it for you. A template wraps a XAML "view" around a data object, with the object being the DataContext of the templated XAML.

Comment: Just have been testing this and it seems to work :) I was sure I did try it before and that it didn't worked, but now it seems to. I was trying several things so maybe that was the problem.. Will test some more and let you know.. Thx!