# Using multiple instances of same user control simultaneously

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am creating an application using wpf and MVVM.  I've run into an issue where one of the controls uses three copies of another control at the same time.  All three need to have their own instance of the related view model.  Currently I have bindings in the user control's view that relate to the view model, but I do not have the control's data context set in its own xaml.

I don't remember where I saw this, but my initial attempt was to use an observable collection like so:
In the model:

```
private ObservableCollection<SignalStrengthViewModel> signalStrengths;

public GyroViewModel()
{
    this.signalStrengths = new ObservableCollection<SignalStrengthViewModel>();
    this.signalStrengths.Add(new SignalStrengthViewModel(Color.FromRgb(0, 128, 255)));
    this.signalStrengths.Add(new SignalStrengthViewModel(Color.FromRgb(63, 163, 153)));
    this.signalStrengths.Add(new SignalStrengthViewModel(Color.FromRgb(121, 132, 196)));
```

}

and the xaml of the containing control:

```
<controls:SignalStrengthUserControl x:Name="Link1SignalStrengthControl" DataContext="{Binding SignalStrengths[0], Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
<controls:SignalStrengthUserControl x:Name="Link2SignalStrengthControl" DataContext="{Binding SignalStrengths[1], Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
<controls:SignalStrengthUserControl x:Name="Link3SignalStrengthControl" DataContext="{Binding SignalStrengths[2], Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

This doesn't seem to actually bind the instances of the control with the instances of the view models.  I've also tried moving the list to the code behind containing control's xaml with no change in the result.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I have seen questions here and elsewhere that use data templates for text boxes, but I haven't found a way to make that work here (and they were all for text boxes).

Some of the other questions I've looked at:

[A SIMPLE PATTERN FOR CREATING RE-USEABLE USERCONTROLS IN WPF / SILVERLIGHT](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html)
[Multiple instances of a wpf user control all use the same viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909982/multiple-instances-of-a-wpf-user-control-all-use-the-same-viewmodel)

Comment: Shouldn't that mode be `OneWay` instead of `OneWayToSource`? From the code you've shown, it looks like it *should* work other than that.

Comment: The only other oddity I see is that you are using a `List` to hold the data sources when it looks like it is hard coded to have exactly 3.  It *should* work that way, but it smells a little odd.  If there are always exactly 3, i would have just made an individual property for each of them, barring any other technical requirement for having them in a list.

Comment: Yeah, a list is probably not actually needed.  Changing it from OneWayToSource to OneWay fixed it though.  No clue why that was blocking it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Mode` on your bindings are set incorrectly, they should be `OneWay`.  `OneWayToSource` is used to move data from the "target" element back to the source of the bindings, almost exactly opposite of what you are trying to do.

More details about what each `BindingMode` does can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode(v=vs.110).aspx).